# Detect if first element is visible w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a div with an overflow set to hide elements.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; height:40px">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible in jquery to detect if the first item is visible or  hidden? Is it possible to detect the same for the last item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jQuery's `.position` to figure out if the offset of the element from the parent is greater than the height of the parent.

Code sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ERFV5/)